# APK: native libraries name issues related to version number (SO.X.Y)

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, apk

### Issue

Built APK looks wrong and prevents my application from loading its native library because it cannot find a dependency when calling `dlopen()`: `dlopen failed: library "libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0" not found`.

### jniLibs content

My `jniLibs` directory, for the target platform, contains the following files:

- `libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0` is the "real" shared object.
- `libboost_filesystem.so` is a symlink to `libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0`

### APK Content

After building, the APK contains a `libboost_filesystem.so` which *now* is the binary object (not a symlink).
It seems like Android build system followed the symlink, grabbed content of the "pointed-to" file, but used the name of the symlink instead.

I have tried to remove the symlink from the `jniLibs` folder, but doing that it seems that the `xxx.so.VERSION` files are then ignored.

### Question

How can I embed my "full name" shared object into the `jniLibs` without the Android build system messing with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You should avoid versioning the so file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058227/192373 for instructions.

It's also quite natural that Android does not support this technique, because your native libraries belong to your APK and no version conflict can occur.

Consider linking boost filesystem statically to avoid extra lookup.